# Can you use AJAX page methods to make non-static function calls?

Tags: ajax, pagemethods

Javascript:

```
PageMethods.DragEventToEvent(event.text(), event.parent().parent().text(), cell.parent().text(),   OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
```

C# Function:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static void DragEventToEvent(string evt, string startCell, string endCell) {
       //Blahblah
    }
```

This "works", but it's a static call. I need a non-static call here. Can it be done with page methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant use non-static function calls with PageMethods.

Use System.Web.UI.ICallbackEventHandler instead.

[Implementing Client Callbacks Programmatically Without Postbacks in ASP.NET Web Pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx)

Example 1:

[Asynchronous client script callbacks](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/asynchronous-client-script-callbacks/)

Example 2:

[Using ICALLBACKEventHandler in ASP.NET](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=119)

GL HF ;)

Comment: Haha, thanks for the response. This project has long since stopped being my responsibility but maybe I'll pass along this note.